# print navigation with sub menu

Tags: php, sql, recursion, foreach

So what i want to do is to print navigation with submenus. What i have:

SQL table of menu items(ID, CAPTION, MODULE, PARENT_ID).
So parent menu items obviously have PARENT_ID at 0. When sub item is added PARENT_ID matches the ID of the parent item. How one could print such navigation with foreach or maybe recursive function.

HTML is from bootstrap:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, the most complicated part for me is the parent part. I can print all elements with no problem. However, i do not know how to make a function that would check if a particular parent element has children (then print as drop-down) and if not print as simple li element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easy. You have to call `function menu` in itself. After you have to check if there submenu has, you will create `ul` element with `dropdown` class.

```
//call function
echo menu(0);

function menu($id){

    $return = "";

    // Your SQL query
    $data = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE 1=1 AND `parent_id`='" . $id . "'";

    foreach($data   as $key =>  $row){

        // calling menu to check is there any parent elements.

        $subs   = menu($row->id);

        if($subs!=''){
           $liClass = 'class="dropdow"';
           $aHrefAttr = 'class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"';
        }else{
           $liClass = '';
           $aHrefAttr = '';
        }

        $return .= '<li '.$liClass.'><a ' . $aHrefAttr . ' href="'.$url.'">'.$row->title.'</a>';

        if($subs!=''){
            $return .= "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n";
            $return .=  $subs;
            $return .= "</ul>\n";
        }
        $return .= "</li>\n";
    }

    return $return;
}
```